# How to print front-end log messages on the server console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to print log messages to the server console from front-end?

For Example, if my GUI HTML pages is running on JBOSS server. I want to write logs to the server console ie, "SERVER.log" file generated on the JBOSS server.
(Just like Sysout() for printing simple debugging messages.)

Comment: What do you mean by "the server console"?

Comment: `console.log = function (message) { $.post("/api/logs", { message: message } }`

Answer (score 2):

You could overwrite the default `console.log` api or use another method;

```
var logHandler = {
    send: function(args) {
        $.post("URL", {
            messages: arguments
        });
    }
}

window.defaultConsoleLog = console.log;

console.log = function() {
    logHandler.send(arguments)

    defaultConsoleLog.call(this, arguments);
}
```

*Not tested code*

I would **recommend** not overwriting default behavior of the browser, but instead have a "proxy"

```
var logger = function() {
    logHandler.send(arguments);

    console.log.call(this, arguments)
}
```

And then use `logger("Test")` instead of `console.log("Test")`

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear on the "server console" part and your specific requirements?

If all you need is to capture activity on the server, I suggest you look into something like log4javascript.

http://log4javascript.org/docs/index.html

Comment: This should be a comment, not answer

Comment: Is there a way to print log messages to the server console from front-end?

For Example, if my GUI HTML pages is running on JBOSS server. I want to write logs to the server console ie, "SERVER.log" file generated on the JBOSS server. (Just like Sysout() for printing simple debugging messages.)